# Got a little issue with setTimeout in Javascript - it isnt properly working

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So I have a checkbox. And I am trying to make it so that when you click the checkbox, it shows a message, pauses, and then does another thing. I know you can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` - I am using `setTimeout`. Anyways, enough waffling, here is the JavaScript code:

```js
function real() {
  if (checker2.checked == true) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      checker2.disabled = true
      const p = document.createElement("p")
      p.innerHTML = "Yes! You are human (or at least have a 99.9% of being)"
      document.body.appendChild(p)
      p.style.color = "white"
    }, 5000)
    console.log("This should print after 5 seconds")

  }
}
```

The problem isn't the checkbox or anything like that the problem is it doesn't pause for five seconds. It just skips straight to printing it. I'm not sure what's wrong. I appreciate help. Thanks

Comment: Anything that you want to excute after 5s should go inside the setTimeout() callback function. Code outside of that (such as your `console.log()`) will run before the callback executes.

Comment: the issue is your statement `This should print after 5 seconds` is incorrect

Comment: JavaScript is an asynchronous  language, it will not stop executing other things until the setTimeout is executed if you want the line to be printed after 5 seconds, then you should put into the callback function itself.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
function real(){
    if(checker2.checked == true){
        setTimeout(function(){
            checker2.disabled = true
            const p = document.createElement("p")
            p.innerHTML = "Yes! You are human (or at least have a 99.9% of being)"
            document.body.appendChild(p)
            p.style.color = "white"
            console.log("This should print after 5 seconds")},5000)
}}
```

as only the callback function, you give to `setTimeout()` as parameter, will be executed after 5 seconds and not the following code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) works. The function inside `setTimeout()` will be executed once the timer expires.

The following should be working as you expect it:

```js
function real() {
  if (checker2.checked == true) {

      checker2.disabled = true
      const p = document.createElement("p")
      p.innerHTML = "Yes! You are human (or at least have a 99.9% of being)"
      document.body.appendChild(p)
      p.style.color = "white"

      setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("This should print after 5 seconds")
      }, 5000)
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay your print statement, it must be inside `setTimeout` as a callback. See the following example.

```js
function real() {
  if (document.getElementById("checker2").checked) {

    checker2.disabled = true
    const p = document.createElement("p")
    p.innerHTML = "Yes! You are human (or at least have a 99.9% of being)"
    document.body.appendChild(p)
    p.style.color = "white";

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("This should print after 5 seconds")
    }, 5000);

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checker2" name="checker2" value="Check it" onClick="real()">
```